# Passing variables to classes, importing modules

Tags: python

I would like to replace a part of the code with results generated elsewhere (here **my_results**).

My code (not working, not sure why)

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

from Circle_Import_py import *

my_results=np.ones(shape=(2,3))
print(Circle(8).area())
```

and the **Circle_Import_py**

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

class Circle():
    def __init__(self, r):
        self.radius = r

    def area(self):
        return self.radius**2*3.14
    pd.DataFrame(my_results).to_csv("test.csv")
```

The code generates NameError: name 'my_results' is not defined.

However, when I use below:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

my_results=np.ones(shape=(2,3))
pd.DataFrame(my_results).to_csv("test1.csv")

class Circle():
    def __init__(self, r):
        self.radius = r

    def area(self):
        return self.radius**2*3.14
    pd.DataFrame(my_results).to_csv("test2.csv")
   

print(Circle(8).area())
```

All is working.
How should I access **my_results** for class **Circle**?

Comment: A module can't refer to variables from the calling script.

Comment: And even if it could, you're importing the module before you assign the `my_results` variable.

Comment: Code in a class that isn't in a method executes when the class is defined, not when instances are created. So there aren't any results when you define the `Circle` class.

Comment: If you want your Circle instance to have access to my_results, you need to pass it in as a parameter to the constructor, and then modify your code to work with that paran.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your module can't refer to this variable because it is out of it's scope.

In your second example, `my_result` is declared within the scope of `Circle`.

Try passing `my_result` to `Circle`'s constructor like this:

```py
class Circle():
    def __init__(self, r, my_results):
        self.radius = r
        self.my_results = my_results

    def area(self):
        pd.DataFrame(self.my_results).to_csv("test.csv")
        return self.radius**2*3.14
```

I assumed you wanted to call `pd.DataFrame(self.my_results).to_csv("test.csv")` in `area`, but if you want to call it elsewhere, simply create your function and move the line at the correct place.